# G711a and G711u codec enable in PJSIP

Tags: ios, sip, codec, pjsip

PJSIP - 2.9

I am trying to enable ALAW and ULAW code into my iOS app. I passed list of codec for account add with G711A/8000/1 and G711U/8000/1 but when I make call and check the INVTE I did not see anyone of codec there.

Whereas if I add another codec I can see that enabled in INVITE. I tried to check whether these codecs has some other dependency or it has be enabled like G729.

Please help me if someone can. Thank you

Comment: did you try to put #define PJMEDIA_HAS_G711_CODEC 1 in config_site.h ? you should check first it these codecs are present in pjsua_enum_codecs() , if yes try to put highest priority to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically G711a refers to PCMA and G711u refer as PCMU. So if you want to enable G711A or ALAW that means you need to use PCMA/8000/1 and for G711U or ULAW you need to have PCMU/8000/1

It is a bit confusing initially for me but now it's pretty clear.